# How to validate & diagnose a gamma GLM in R?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, references, gamma-distribution, diagnostic

I am fitting a generalized linear model in R with the log link and I need to validate and diagnose my model. I have never worked with the GLM in the past.

- Is there an article or any references I can look for that would help me learn how to diagnose the model?
- Does anyone have any tips for me on how to do this or even just how to get started?
- What is the difference between the deviance and $r^2$?
- Can we calculate the SS error in the GLM?

(The best way for me to understand is to give formulas and explain what they are used for.)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using gamma? (It's a less frequently used model.) Can you say a little about your situation, data, and goals? Also, is there something specific that you are worried about (do you think there may be a certain problem w/ your model), or are you just wanting to do your due diligence?

Comment: Faraway's Extending the linear model (...) has some GLM diagnostics in 6.4 (page 135).

Answer (score 11):

-Look at Chapter 6 or Section 6.3.4 in the book "[Statistical Models in S](http://books.google.ca/books?id=uyfvAAAAMAAJ&q=Statistical%20Models%20in%20S&dq=Statistical%20Models%20in%20S&hl=en&sa=X&ei=A1TNUJONDOWN0QHFr4GYDw&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAA)" by Chambers and Hastie.  Also you many want to check the package [boot](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/boot/boot.pdf) and function "glm.diag.plots" (Diagnostics plots for generalized linear models). Here are some code with gamma family and the plots from the help file.

```
library(boot)
data(leuk, package = "MASS")
leuk.mod <- glm(time ~ ag-1+log10(wbc), family = Gamma(log), data = leuk)
leuk.diag <- glm.diag(leuk.mod)
glm.diag.plots(leuk.mod, leuk.diag)
```

[image]
 These plots are (upper left: residual vs linear predictor, upper right: normal scores plots of standardized deviance residuals, Lower left: approximate Cook statistics against leverage, Lower right: the plot of Cook statistic)
- See [Introduction to Generalized Linear Models](http://statmath.wu.ac.at/courses/heather_turner/glmCourse_001.pdf)
- Have a look at the above reference, pages 42 and 44 to see the difference of deviance and $r^2$.
- The following code shows how to find SSE (but normally you don't need it!)

```
#Create a data set
counts <- c(18,17,15,20,10,20,25,13,12)
outcome <- gl(3,1,9)
treatment <- gl(3,3)
print(d.AD <- data.frame(treatment, outcome, counts))
#Fitting poisson GLM
glm.D93 <- glm(counts ~ outcome + treatment, family=poisson())
summary(glm.D93)
# In the following, resid(glm.D93) extracts residuals of the fitted model glm.D93 
SSE=sum(resid(glm.D93))^2
SSE
[1] 0.04638682
```

Comment: is there a faster way instead of this leuk.diag <- glm.diag(leuk.mod) it is taking for ever with my data to execute.